# How to get exact page as seen in browser from requests library

Tags: javascript, python, html, regex, python-requests

I am trying to get the percentage of flight's journey completed by requesting a simple get request to google `https://www.google.co.in/search?q=<flight-id>`
Which gives back a nice material card, something like this :[image]

Now google already calculates the percentage of flight journy compleated and is given in `<div style="height:30px;min-width:6px;position:relative;width:2%`.
Now it's obvious that `width:2%` is the percentage of journey compleated.
My problem is that i am unable to find a suitable **regex(or bs4 query)** for it. It's been hours.
I tried all this:

- `re.findall('<div style="height:30px;min-width:6px;position:relative;width:2%', r.text)`
- `re.findall('<div style="height:30px;*">, r.text)`
- `soup.find('tbody', {'class': 'ts'})`

   and some more regex that are lost in my terminal, i'll update them as soon as i can find. But my point is, i cannot even get to the specified `<div>` by copy pasting it as a whole.

And as for the code i am using to request the page:

```
 head = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}`<br>
 r = requests.get(r'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ai-430', headers=head)`<br/><br/>
```

***EDIT***: As pointed out by ***@tripleee*** I am not getting the exact page as seen in browser (the material card is not available when requested from terminal) ergo regex is not the problem
how can I get the exact same page as seen in interactive browser from requests library or any other library available for python

***PS***: I am not try to get the percentage journey completion every second, but once every half an hour or so. And I will send the status as a text message using twilio's library. I usually have to pick up my elder brother and getting constant text about the journey detail will help me plan ahead/

Contrart to what's pointed out, my question does not have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210903/can-google-flights-data-be-queried-from-google-api)
While the latter deals with the specific API that are used for getting flight data. My question has least of concerns with it and is more focused on [how to get specific information from a AJAX enabled material box](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97260/discussion-between-jarwin-and-tripleee)

Comment: you're confident that the elements are available when your code trots out looking for them(it) ? -- edit : you mention copy-paste - can you provide a fiddler?

Comment: Do you fetch the page successfully?  With `curl` on the command line I get `curl: (35) error:0D0C50A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:unknown message digest algorithm`; then with `curl -k` I get a 430 Forbidden.

Comment: @BrandtSolovij Umm, while browsing with Mozilla i get the material card. and i am using that as header as well, so theoretically it should get the page same page?

Comment: @tripleee yup,  `r.status_code` was 200 and `r.text` was html gibbrish

Comment: I get HTML gibberish too, but it simply does not contain the flight information.  If it's not there, your problem is not a regex problem.  I can get flight information in my interactive Firefox browser, but the same query from `curl` does not return that result, or much anything like a result.  I'm guessing that's the root cause with `requests` as well; but that's what I'm asking, and you are not providing a useful answer.

Comment: @Jarwin flight status will likely produce an initial value but will be updated periodically. it doesn't make any sense for google to write an initial value to the DOM because there is no SEO SERP value to it - so assume the data is injected itself. Which is why i asked if the elements were available @ your code's runtime

Comment: My guess is that you need Selenium or PhantomJS that executes JavaScript

Comment: @tripleee You were right. i saved the HTML gibbrish in a file and ran a `grep` search on it. Nada. All the other links are there but not the material card. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: My guess is that Google gets this data in machine-readable form from somewhere, and so could you.  Find out where they obtain this.  Googling for "flight information JSON" brings up several promising-looking APIs.

Comment: @tripleee yeah, but most of them are paid API, And it's an unnecessary amount of work to get the percentage journey completion. Why go all that trouble if i can somehow get my hands on the fore-mentioned `div` tag

Comment: @Brandt Solovij I have updated the question

Comment: @Kenji Noguchi can you please shed some more light on it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Google Flights data be queried from Google API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210903/can-google-flights-data-be-queried-from-google-api)

Comment: @triplee the raison d'etre of this questiom is I am trying to get a div element from a webpage. How has that got anything to do with the Google API. I am just fetching the html.

Comment: The replies to the other question include some discussion of why you should avoid screen scraping in the first place if you can. One of the replies there also expands on the PhantomJS suggestion.  You really should read it before dismissing it.

Comment: @tripleee I went through the thread. And while was mainly concerned with how to get flight information; but molecularbear's answer caught my eye. From what i am understanding, the material box gets data from AJAX and that is why it is not avilable when requested from a terminal. And if my perceptions are right now can I do that? I don't have a decent background in JavaScript. PS: I searched the APIs none of them provides live status anyway. And I'd again like to stress the fact that it's alot of unnecessary pain to vo through if I can somehow grab that material card.

Comment: You don't need JavaScript to do the underlying REST query, though understanding how it works will certainly help. Getting the data in machine-readable form has two, no, three distinct benefits: (1) you don't download stuff you don't need (Google will thank you); (2) you don't need to use error-prone, brittle scraping techniques to get the data you want; and (3) using a well-defined protocol and format means you can catch and handle various boundary conditions sanely.  So it's not *unnecessary* and it's not *pain* once you figure it out (at least not compared to screen scraping).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97260/discussion-between-jarwin-and-tripleee).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear:

Do you want get string `2%` from string `<div style="height:30px;min-width:6px;position:relative;width:2%'>`

Or you are not able to select/read the `<div>` object with *JQuery* (so JQuery not found this div)?

Comment: As i mentioned in the comments, I am trying to get `<div style="height:30px;min-width:6px;position:relative;width:2%'>` but while using `urllib` or `requests` the *material box* is not being recived along with the rest of the `HTML`